# Post-Increment of an Post-Increment in C++

Tags: c++, increment

If I use a nested increment operator in C++, such as

```
int a = 1;
int b = (a++)++;
```

It gives a compile-time error:

`error: lvalue required as increment operand`

However, if I write

```
int a = 1;
int b = ++(++a);
```

The new value of `b` becomes 3.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: The reason is value category. A post increment is only possible on an lvalue, but returns an rvalue. Also, please add information to the question by editing the question, not by posting comments.

Comment: But… why even bother… what’s the useful point of even trying to write code like in this question - you’d never write this in production code… would you?

Answer (score 6):

`(a++)` returns a temporary rvalue with an old value of `a`. There is no postincrement operator available to rvalues.

Comment: **What is the value of `b` in "```int a = 1; int b = (a++) + (a++);```"** ??? If it is `2`, then I don't understand all the downvotes on my answer (o_O ) - you say "old value", I say it does not change at all till semi-colon.

Comment: @Top-Master You updated your answer after my answer. Your example above leads undefined behaviour.

Comment: Can you define what's undefined? Do you mean the C++ spec let's the compiler do whatever it wants with "`int b = (a++) + (a++);`" code?

Comment: @Top-Master constant is not rvalue.

Comment: @Top-Master nothing is done after the `;`. You misunderstood something

Comment: @Top-Master Like @S.M said, `b = (a++) + (a++)` is undefined behavior, because C++ doesn't specific the order of evaluation, and it could perform either the first `a++` or the second `a++` first. And it is actually more likely to result to `3` instead of `2`: https://godbolt.org/z/na373bvKG

Comment: But my question was what is the value of `b`, so, no matter which is executed first. (Also, I meant end-of-statement with semi-colon, see the Assembly as proof).

Comment: @Top-Master assembly cannot prove how things are specified by the standard, espcially when the code has UB looking at the assembly can only be misleading

Comment: @Top-Master Both compiler in my link resulted to `3`, which at least says it doesn't have to perform increment after the end of the line.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep thanks man! now I can delete my post in peace. Hmm... does UB mean Upper-Bound? (btw imho rn ppl shorten what shouldn't, yes encryption is fun).

Comment: @Top-Master UB means undefined behavior

Comment: @Top-Master [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a

Comment: Has someone power to remove all undefined-behavior from C++ plz? Or at least, ask for this feature somewhere? Most of *undefined-behavior* is only meant to make Compiler-Implementation simpler (with the cost of making developer lives harder).

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is it doesn't make sense to perform a post-increment to the result that is produced by a post-increment.

Let's first see what exactly `a++` does:

```
int operator++(int)
{
    auto temp = *this;
    *this += 1;
    return temp;
}
```

So when you perform `a++`, `a` would be incremented by `1`, and then it returns a temporary value that is equals to what `a` used to be.

Now imagine if you perform this for a second time, what you are essentially doing is:

```
int post_increment_twice()
{
    auto temp1 = *this;
    *this += 1;
    auto temp2 = temp1;
    temp1 += 1;
    return temp2;
}
```

You would notice that the result is exactly the same as post increment once.

- `*this` was incremented once
- then you return the value `*this` used to be.

---

- In fact, it doesn't make sense to perform a post-increment on any temporary values.

Post-increment performs an increment to the value inside the function. However, by passing in a temporary value, you lose the access the incremented object. And returns a value that is equal to the temporary value before it was incremented.

---

While it is possible to overload a post-increment operator for custom classes to accept temporary values. But with integers, it simply doesn't make sense to accept that, thus it was not allowed.